# Как сделать прокрутку к верху контейнера на React?

Tags: javascript, прокрутка, reactjs

Не получается сделать прокрутку к верху контейнера. Как это можно реализовать?

**Это основная страница:**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import Helmet from 'react-helmet';
import { connect } from 'redux/react';
import { prepareRoute } from '../decorators';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as CompanyActionCreators from '../actions/company';
import CompanyScrollToTop from './company/CompanyScrollToTop';

class CompanyPage extends React.Component {
    render () {
        const {
            props: {

            }
        } = this;

    return (
        <div className="wrapper wrapper--popup wrapper--popup-mod-mobile">                
            <CompanyScrollToTop />
        </div>
    );


  }
}

export default CompanyPage;
```

**Это компонент, который подключаю:**

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

class CompanyScrollToTop extends React.Component {
    render (){
        return(
            <div onclick={this._scrollToTop} className="arrow-scroll-to-top visible-tablet">
            </div>
        );      
    }

    _scrollToTop() {
        const elTop = document.querySelector('body');
        elTop.scrollTop = 0;
    };
}

export default CompanyScrollToTop;
```

Comment: Скриншот добавь, как это у тебя выглядит на странице

Comment: К сожалению, пока что не могу, проект не запущен и договор о неразглашении... Ладно, буду искать проблему, все равно спасибо за отклик!!!

Comment: выведи 2 элемента на пустую страницу, причем тут соглашения. Блоки пустые, никакой информации они не несут

Comment: https://gyazo.com/f0ff744ac076d325e350435bdd104bba
вот скрин

Comment: https://gyazo.com/95856e0b62490e6a9a81d7418a140ca1
гифка еще, там был в конце клик по стрелке

Comment: добавил код, проверил у себя, работает

Comment: Мистика какая-то

Answer (score 1):

**Я делал так:**

```
var scrollNode = document.getElementById('navigationScroll');

scrollNode.scrollTop = 0;
```

`elTop.scrollTo(0, 0);` можешь поменять на `elTop.scrollTop = 0`

Зачем вызывать метод меняющий 2 переменные по `x`, `y`, когда можно напрямую указывать, что именно тебе надо изменить

Ещё ошибка в вызове метода. Ты подписываешься на `this.scrollToTop`, а метода такого нет, есть только `this._scrollToTop`.

PS. `scrollTop` является опцией блока, в котором есть скролл. Его значение указывает на то, на сколько блок внутри отодвинут от дефолтного `0`

**UPD**

```
class CompanyPage extends React.Component {
    render () {
    return (
        <div id="scrolledBlock" style={{overflow: 'auto'}} className="wrapper wrapper--popup wrapper--popup-mod-mobile">
            <div id="myElement" style={{height: 2000}}></div>    
            <CompanyScrollToTop />
        </div>
    );
  }
}

class CompanyScrollToTop extends React.Component {
    _scrollToTop() {
      let scroll = document.getElementById('scrolledBlock');
      scroll.scrollTop = 0;
    }
    render (){
        return(
            <div className="arrow-scroll-to-top visible-tablet">
                <button onClick={this._scrollToTop.bind(this)}>Go top</button>
            </div>
        );      
    }
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, чтобы найти правильный блок, который скороллится и должен скроллится. Если находишь, все заработает

Comment: Не выходит. Понятия не имею в чем проблема, может где-то что-то не то указываю. Вообще мне редактор говорит, что функция почему-то не используется.

Comment: Ну да, у тебя функция вызывается как `this.scrollToTop`, а объявлена как `this._scrollToTop`, добавил в ответ.

Comment: С вашего разрешения скрины прикреплю [https://gyazo.com/e33df737455530e3f21e584aa1821830
[https://gyazo.com/254b7044a675d967e3500c76446a5ec1

Comment: @Jarvis не `.scrollTo`, а `.scrollTop = 0`. Я же не вижу всей картины. Может ты не правильно или ссылаешься не на тот дом объект

Comment: ну да, без полной картины трудно

Comment: @Jarvis так ты правки вносишь? Измени пост, покажи как у тебя выглядит главная страница с кнопкой и блоком со скроллом. Код где блок со скроллом находится. Вопрос то простой. Просто надо найти проблему

Comment: дал код компонента и страницы самой, у блока, который содержит кнопку высота 1000px